# Simpletest PHP scriptable browser... how to test submit a form that has [ ] in the form name (basically in array format)?

Tags: php, simpletest

I am using simpletest, the php scriptable browser and trying to test submit a form that is in array format so its like this:

```
<input id="password" name="session[password]" value="" type="password">
```

Other input names start with "session" so I have to give the full name of each but it doesn't seem to work when I do it like this in my PHP script:

```
$this->setField('session[password]', 'password');
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this properly, or can I set it to look at the input's id instead, since this is always unique, as far as I know, I don't even understand why they chose name rather than ID as the field to use for this...

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the value the user has submitted by looking at `$_POST["session"]["password"]` (assuming the form method was "post", not "get").

You can test it with this simple script:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    die();
}
?>
<form method="post">
<input id="password" name="session[password]" value="" type="password">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```