# Submit an array of values with SimpleTest

Tags: php, simpletest

I'm trying to submit a simple form that has an array of fields:

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='Article[]' id='Article1' />
<input type='text' name='Article[]' id='Article2' />
<input type='text' name='Article[]' id='Article3' />
```

So, how do I set the different fields using SimpleTest?

(p.s. I've seen this question: [Simpletest PHP scriptable browser... how to test submit a form that has [ ] in the form name (basically in array format)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173870/simpletest-php-scriptable-browser-how-to-test-submit-a-form-that-has-in-th) but it doesn't answer my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out one way of doing this is to use setFieldById. Change the code to:

```
$form->setFieldById('Article1', 'Some Article Text 1'); 
$form->setFieldById('Article2', 'Some Article Text 2');
```

And so on. Works perfectly but assumes you can generate unique IDs for each field -- not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$form->setField('Article', array("Some article text", "Some article text2"));`

Comment: There is similar example in [documentation of SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/en/form_testing_documentation.html#multiple). It seems buggy, as it uses `name='crud'` instead of `name='crud[]'` for inputs, but it shows that SimpleTest is supposed to be able to set values in fields with the same names. I would try `'Article[]'` (not just `'Article'`) as the first argument though :)

Comment: Actually, this method doesn't quite work because there are three Article[] fields and SimpleTest sets each to the array. That means that I get 9 values instead of the three I want. 

I figured out a method of doing this. Posting it as an answer for reference.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: (simpletest.php)

```
<?php
if( isset( $_REQUEST['submit']))
    print_r( $_POST['Article']);
?>
<form method='post' action='simpletest.php'> 
<input type='text' name='Article[]' id='Article1' />
<input type='text' name='Article[]' id='Article2' />
<input type='text' name='Article[]' id='Article3' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm asking. I want to submit this thing automatically with simpletest. Normally, we do this like so: 

$form->setField('Article[]', "Some article text"); 

But I can't submit more than one values using this method.